# How to change aurelia slickgrid rowdetail "+" icon to another?

Tags: aurelia, slickgrid, aurelia-slickgrid

I am using the [aurelia-slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/aurelia-slickgrid/wiki/Row-Detail) library with the "**RowDetailView**" option, where we have the following icon:

> [image]

Is it possible to override maybe the gridOptions somewhere, or anywhere else in order to use another icon?
Currently I am using the rowdetail options like that:

```
    gridOptions = {
    ....
     rowDetailView: {
    ....
    //is there something that can change the default icon?
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the icons by changing any of the icons associated [SASS variables](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/blob/19222c88e5e3e13bfc2abb744cb17d3e54dd9134/packages/common/src/styles/_variables.scss#L244-L255). You could also use CSS Variables, see at the bottom.

The defaults variables have the following Font-Awesome 4 icons (the hex value can be found from the Font-Awesome website), if you use a Font then you'll always have an associated Hex value:

```
$slick-detail-view-icon-collapse: "\f056";
$slick-detail-view-icon-expand:   "\f055";
```

When you use a Font then you'll always have an Hex value (as shown above), you could use any other Font (not just Font-Awesome) but if you do then don't forget to also change the associated SASS variable (below is for Font-Awesome 4)

```
$slick-icon-font-family: "FontAwesome";
```

You can also use SVGs, that is how I created the Salesforce & [Material](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/blob/master/packages/common/src/styles/_variables-theme-material.scss) Themes (copy SVG path from [Material Design Icons](https://materialdesignicons.com/)), for example

```
$slick-detail-view-icon-collapse: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="darkgray" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M17,13H7V11H17M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2Z"></path></svg>');
$slick-detail-view-icon-expand:   url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="darkgray" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M17,13H13V17H11V13H7V11H11V7H13V11H17M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2Z"></path></svg>');
```

You could also use CSS Variables which are also available via the same name by replacing the `$` prefix with `--`

```css
:root {
    --slick-detail-view-icon-collapse: "\f056";
    --slick-detail-view-icon-expand: "\f055";
}
```

and actually I wrote all of this answer, but in fact it's also explained very well in the multiple Wikis that I created on the same topic, [Styling - Wiki](https://github.com/ghiscoding/aurelia-slickgrid/wiki/Styling) and [SVG Icons - Wiki](https://github.com/ghiscoding/aurelia-slickgrid/wiki/SVG--Icons), so you can also check them out.